# Fading in changing background images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that switches between background images based on where I scroll.  I am able to get the background images to switch correctly, but it's been requested that I have the background images `fadeIn()` instead of simply change.  Basically, I'm looping through the background images and I want the previous one to `fadeOut()` and the next one to `fadeIn()`.  Is it possible to do this?  If so, how?  Here's the script.

```
$("#scroll").on("slidestart", function(ev, ui){
    $(this).on("mousemove touchmove", function(){
        var slider_pos = $("span").offset().top;

        $("#menu").find(".schematics").each(function(ev){
            var schematic_id = $(this).data("id").split("_")[0];
            var schematic_top = $(this).offset().top;
            var schematic_height = $(this).height();
            var schematic_bottom = (schematic_top + schematic_height);

            var url = $(this).data("url");
```

Here's where the background images change.  I thought adding `fadeIn()` after the css operation would work, but it doesn't.

```
            if((slider_pos >= schematic_top) && (slider_pos <= schematic_bottom)){
                $("#plane_image").css("background-image", "url(" +url +")").fadeIn("slow");

                $(".vis").hide();
                $(".title").hide();
                $("#" +schematic_id +"_list").show();
                $("#" +schematic_id +"_head").show();
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: You won't see the images with a fiddle, so you won't be able to see what's going on.

Comment: I would have thought `fadeIn()` would do the trick...Could there be a delay as the image loads? So that it loads and shows after `fadeIn` completes?

Comment: @Ted, I thought there was a delay as well, but there isn't it's just not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's fadeIn and fadeOut functions have a "complete" function, which is called after the animation has completed. You could try something like this.

```
var slideTimeout;   // global var for any slider timeout
if((slider_pos >= schematic_top) && (slider_pos <= schematic_bottom)){
    if(slideTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(slideTimeout);  // clears the timeout if we detect a new slide movement.
    }
    slideTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#plane_image").fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $("#plane_image").css("background-image", "url(" +url +")").fadeIn("slow", function(){
                $(".vis").hide();
                $(".title").hide();
                $("#" +schematic_id +"_list").show();
                $("#" +schematic_id +"_head").show();
            });
        }); 
    }, 1000);   // it will wait 1 second before firing the method again
}
```

Or you could do it the boolean way.

```
var inVisibleRegion = false;
if((slider_pos >= schematic_top) && (slider_pos <= schematic_bottom)){
    if(!inVisibleRegion) {
        $("#plane_image").fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $("#plane_image").css("background-image", "url(" +url +")").fadeIn("slow", function(){
                $(".vis").hide();
                $(".title").hide();
                $("#" +schematic_id +"_list").show();
                $("#" +schematic_id +"_head").show();
            });
        }); 
        inVisibleRegion = true;
    }
}
else {
    inVisibleRegion = false;
}
```

For further insight, check out [jQuery fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [jQuery fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/).

Comment: I have a further question about this.  The solution works, but it continually fades in the image, even after it's made the switch.  How do I stop that?

Comment: Ah, okay. You may need a time out on your scrolling function. I think that because this will fire when the slider_pos is between two values, it will fire for every time this is detected (which is likely happening on every pixel movement). I'll update my answer with a bit more code.

Comment: In addition to this, you could also just use a boolean variable. I've edited my answer again.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what it's doing.  thanks for the answer and the update, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Start a fadeOut, then load the new img and call fadeIn, which fires on completion of the fadeOut (bg = your element)

```
bg.fadeOut('slow', function () {
   bg.load(function () {bg.fadeIn();});
   bg.attr("src", newbgdrc);
});
```