# Fading out one background image and fading in another when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a feature that allows images to fade in and fade out as a person scrolls within the page.  Similar to [My previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653629/fading-in-changing-background-images) instead of having the script find the position of the scroll handle, I simply want the scroll bar to loop through the images in the object and have them `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` as the user scrolls.  How would I accomplish this?

```
var Plane_Images = {
    Skin: {
        name: "Skin Schematic",
        image: "images/Top-2.png",
        schematics: [["Nose Wheel Steering", "NST"], ["B", "B.1"], ["C", "C.1"], ["D", "D.1"]]
    },
    Structure: {
        name: "Structure Schematic",
        image: "images/ata21-2.png",
        schematics: [["Landing Gear Handle", "TRO"], ["F", "F.1"], ["G", "G.1"], ["H", "H.1"]]
    },
    Electrics: {
        name: "Electrics Schematic",
        image: "images/ata26-2.png",
        schematics: [["I", "I.1"], ["J", "J.1"], ["K", "K.1"], ["L", "L.1"]]
    },
    Fuel: {
        name: "Fuel Schematic",
        image: "images/Top-2.png",
        schematics: [["M", "M.1"], ["N", "N.1"], ["O", "O.1"], ["P", "P.1"]]
    }
}
```

So far I'm able to continuously `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` one image, but not the others.  Here's my current script.

```
for(var images in Plane_Images){
    var image_src = Plane_Images[images].image;

    $("#scroll").on("slidestart", function(){
        $(this).on("mousemove touchmove", function(){
            $("#plane_image").css("background-image", "url(" +image_src +")").fadeOut("slow");
            $("#plane_image").css("background-image", "url(" +image_src +")").fadeIn("slow");
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle?

Comment: I could, but you wouldn't see the images and you wouldn't see the jquery ui scroll bar.

Comment: you can add some sample images from a image hosting site.

Comment: Still won't be able to see the jQuery Ui scrollbar though

Comment: i think it might be available on the CDN and you can just hook it up in the fiddle by passing in the url in the external resources section.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in your use of the `for` loop. What you're doing is loading multiple triggers against the same event. When the events are triggered, they'll all run one after another on every `mousemove` event.

In order to loop through the images, you'll need to have a function capable of determining the next in the sequence, which I've called `getNextPlaneImage()`. This loops from `0` to `imagesList.length - 1` and then continues from `0` again, where `imagesList` is an array of the keys of your `Plane_Images` JS object. We can use an index `i=0,1,2...` against this list to pick the "next" key, and use that to retrieve the image.

Finally, you'll want to be calling `.css()` and `.fadeIn()` on a callback of `.fadeOut()`, otherwise you'll see the background image change before the `fadeOut()` animation is finished.

To simplify things in the example below, I've opted for a `button` with an `onclick` that triggers a `nextImage` callback.

```
var imagesList = [];

for(var images in Plane_Images){
    imagesList.push(images);
}

var i = 0;

function getNextPlaneImage() {
  var plane_image = Plane_Images[imagesList[i]].image;
  i = (i+1) % imagesList.length;
  return plane_image;
}


$('#scroll').on("nextImage", function(){
 $("#plane_image").fadeOut({
   duration: 'slow',
   complete: function () {
     $(this).css("background-image", "url(" +getNextPlaneImage() +")").fadeIn('slow');
   }
 });
});
```

```js
var Plane_Images = {
    Skin: {
        name: "Skin Schematic",
        image: "http://placehold.it/200x300",
        schematics: [["Nose Wheel Steering", "NST"], ["B", "B.1"], ["C", "C.1"], ["D", "D.1"]]
    },
    Structure: {
        name: "Structure Schematic",
        image: "http://placehold.it/200x200",
        schematics: [["Landing Gear Handle", "TRO"], ["F", "F.1"], ["G", "G.1"], ["H", "H.1"]]
    },
    Electrics: {
        name: "Electrics Schematic",
        image: "http://placehold.it/200x100",
        schematics: [["I", "I.1"], ["J", "J.1"], ["K", "K.1"], ["L", "L.1"]]
    },
    Fuel: {
        name: "Fuel Schematic",
        image: "http://placehold.it/300x200",
        schematics: [["M", "M.1"], ["N", "N.1"], ["O", "O.1"], ["P", "P.1"]]
    }
};

var imagesList = [];

for(var images in Plane_Images){
    imagesList.push(images);
}

var i = 0;

function getNextPlaneImage() {
  var plane_image = Plane_Images[imagesList[i]].image;
  i = (i+1) % imagesList.length;
  return plane_image;
}


$('#scroll').on("nextImage", function(){
 $("#plane_image").fadeOut({
   duration: 'slow',
   complete: function () {
     $(this).css("background-image", "url(" +getNextPlaneImage() +")").fadeIn('slow');
   }
 });
});
```

```css
#plane_image {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: black center no-repeat;
  border: 2px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="scroll">
  <button onclick="$(this).trigger('nextImage');">
     Next
  </button>
</div>

<div id="plane_image"></div>
```